# Deploying a gradle script from Jenkins using the artifactory plugin

Tags: jenkins-plugins, artifactory, gradle-release-plugin

I'm trying to deploy a build from jenkins using the artifactory invocation of gradle plugin and get a an HTTP error  302, going through the log looks like there's a checksum problem that cannot be skipped:

**13:35:41.463 [DEBUG] [org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.task.BuildInfoBaseTask] Failed checksum deploy of checksum '8d80bb7f1bf2f0457baa3ad7379348c5ecbf2535' with statusCode: 302
13:35:41.466 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager] Get connection for route HttpRoute[{}->http://artifactory.edegem.eu.thmulti.com]** 
....
13:35:41.470 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator] Connecting 
**13:35:41.503 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection] Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 302 Found**

Any clue?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

302 is a status code for redirects, which means that your Artifactory is not located at 'http://artifactory.edegem.eu.thmulti.com' but in some other location. Browser follows the redirect to the new place (that's the reason you can browse Artifactory under this URL), but Artifactory networking is not. Please verify the 'real' location of Artifactory and point your Jenkins plugin to it.

Comment: Hi Baruch, you were right the real location was different from the one I was pointing in Jenkins. Thanks a lot!!!