# Unable to deploy the artifacts to jfrog using maven deploy command

Tags: maven

I want to deploy artifacts to my company's JFrog Artifactory server.
I am getting the following error:

> Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.companyname.baseline.base:xyz.jar from/to companyname-artifactory-snapshot (http://maven.companyname.com/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/): Failed to transfer file: http://maven.companyname.com/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/com/companyname/baseline/base/xyz/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/xyz-2.0.0-20160820.050630-1.jar. Return code is: 302

Here is the command I am passing from bamboo Maven task.

```
clean deploy -U -X -DaltDeploymentRepository=companyname-artifactory-snapshot::default::http://maven.companyname.com/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/ -Dmaven.test.skip=true -DBuildSystem=companyname-Bamboo -DBuildNumber=${bamboo.buildNumber} "-DBuildPlan=${bamboo.buildPlanName}" -DSVNRevisionNumber=${bamboo.custom.svn.revision.number} -DSVNLastRevisionNumber=${bamboo.custom.svn.lastchange.revision.number}
```

This is my `settings.xml` file:

```
<servers>
    <server>
        <username>admin</username>
        <password>password</password>
        <id>central</id>
    </server>
    <server>
        <username>admin</username>
        <password>password</password>
        <id>snapshots</id>
    </server>
    <server>
        <id>companyname-site-deploy</id>
        <username></username>
        <password></password>
    </server>
    <server>
        <id>companyname-artifactory-snapshot</id>
        <username>xyz</username>
        <password>abc</password>
    </server>
    <server>
        <id>companyname-artifactory-release</id>
        <username>xyz</username>
        <password>abc</password>
    </server>
</servers>
```

I cannot use `distributionManagement` in the POM files as my dev team is not interested.

How can I pass the exact parameters to solve this issue? I am confused which id to use for JFrog as there are 4 in the servers list.

Comment: Checkout that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16665173/deploying-a-gradle-script-from-jenkins-using-the-artifactory-plugin

Comment: I guess I used the correct URL, I got it from the jfrog distribution management section, when I click on "Libs-snapshots-local" in my jfrog artifactory, on the right side pane i saw this section                                       ------

Comment: can someone please reply?

Comment: Am unable to get this could someone please elaborate and answer my above question?

Comment: can someone reply ?